# How to use two WhereIn with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple query, where $clubs and $user_ids are array. I want to use two WhereIn's in the same query.For example $clubs = array(1,2,3) and $user_id = array(25,30,40). And there is an entry in DB as this user_id =25 and corresponding club_id = 1. I want to list, user_id = 25 from the query result.

```
$query = \DB::table('users_clubs')          
            ->WhereIn('user_id', $user_ids)
            ->WhereIn('club_id',$clubs)
            ->lists('user_id');
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem, if yes, please post the solution.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I solved, i think i used left join to solve that issue.Also, two WhereIn can't use like that, i think.

Comment: Can you post your own answer that will be better and mark that as solution.

Comment: Ok.Sure. I need little time to find that code. It was done days ago, and i actually don't remember where i was applid it.

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow the code of whereIn in core

```
public function whereIn($column, $values, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
{
    $type = $not ? 'NotIn' : 'In';

    // ... irrelevant code omitted ...

    $this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'column', 'values', 'boolean');

    $this->addBinding($values, 'where');

    return $this;
}
```

It does not seems it is possible directly , but if you can override it in some way , it may be helpful.

Another way is using advance where

```
DB::table('users_clubs')
            ->Where(function($query)
            {
                foreach( $user_ids as $user_id ){
                    $query->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
                }

            })
            ->Where(function($query)
            {
                foreach( $clubs as $club){
                    $query->where('club_id', '=', $club);
                }
            })
            ->get();
```

**Not tested it but it seems it may work with some modification .**

Comment: @JintoAntony ok, let me know the status after using it, or if you got any other solution please post it .

Comment: any error or you got  wrong out put , you can use one closer update whatever you got , then I will try to modify this.

Comment: Got out pull a null array, its not matching correctly i think.

Comment: `$query->where('club_id', '=', $club);` think how we can change it , but first do try $query->where(1); and check if you are getting something .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103582/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-jinto-antony).

Answer (score 1):

are you getting any error ? or didn't tried your query ? you can use multiple `whereIn()` as much as you want. after `WhereIn()` add `get()` then `lists()`

**eg** try this

```
$query = \DB::table('users_clubs')          
            ->WhereIn('user_id', $user_ids)
            ->WhereIn('club_id',$clubs)
            ->get()
            ->lists('user_id');
```

Comment: what error/issue you are getting, atleast give us some clue so we can help you accordingly